# Difference between auto and preferExternal instal location Android manifest

Tags: android, location, installation, manifest

What is the difference between `auto` and `preferExternal` instal locations in android manifest? Both options can instal application on External memory. Is it something big and important? Which is better to set?

Comment: see here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html

Answer (score 1):

If you declare `preferExternal`, you request that your application be installed on the external storage, but the system does not guarantee that your application will be installed on the external storage. If the external storage is full, the system will install it on the internal storage.

If you declare `auto`, you indicate that your application may be installed on the external storage, but you don't have a preference of install location. The system will decide where to install your application based on several factors. The user can also move your application between the two locations.

reference 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html